# UIAlertView window popup when app is closed or running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I did some research on UIAlertView and I understand the basics of it.

Here is my feature requirement -

The app should create UIAlertView window at a certain time with two buttons, Yes & NO.  And based on what the user selects, the app create another UIAlertView window and so on.  I wanted to know if its possible to keep track of the Yes and NO even when the app is closed or running in background.

Also, I know its possible to create a UIAlertView via push notification but is it possible to send the Yes or No selection to a server via web service when app is closed or running in background?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my little knowledge, you **can't do** the things when app is closed or running in background.

Comment: Just to confirm: this is definitely not possible.

Comment: But then how does the Alarm app work. When you press the snooze button, the alarm snoozes and then rings again after 5 mins without opening the alarm app correct. Is that because its apple's in built app?

Comment: Of course you *can* do it - API is right there. Just can't upload to the appstore with it. ;)